# Open MIME type in Firefox via online software

Tags: firefox, mime-types

How can I tell Firefox to open a MIME type using an online software?

For instance: When clicking on a link to a Word document I want Firefox to take the URL and call https://docs.google.com/viewer?url= and pass the URL of the Word document to the parameter "url". I know there are addins like "Google Docs Viewer", but I'm looking for a general way which is possible for several different online applications.

I did not find a Firefox Addin that handles this general case. Do I need to implement a Firefox Addin for that or can this be handled by the Firefox MIME types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Open IT Online](http://www.openitonline.com/) firefox-addon, it adds a new option to *Downloads* dialog to open the file in Google Docs.
or use [Google Docs Viewer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/48971/) for right-click context menu.

Comment: Open IT Online is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!